# Laravel 11 Specifying a Custom Model for Sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, stateless, laravel-11

I need to specify a custom table name and schema for Sanctum in Laravel 11 because we use multiple schemas. To do this, I must create a custom model overriding `PersonAccessToken`.

Sanctum provides a method for specifying the model:

```
Sanctum::userPersonalAccessModelTokenModel(CustomPersonalAccessToken::class);
```

Previously, this would have gone into `AuthServiceProvider.php` in the boot method, but with Laravel 11, that file is no longer there. I need to know how to make Laravel aware of the class I want to use. Here is the class for reference:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumPersonalAccessToken;

class CustomPersonalAccessToken extends SanctumPersonalAccessToken
{
    protected $table = 'vendorinv.PersonalAccessToken';
}
```

I've tried the solution from the docs by adding it to the service provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use App\Models\CustomPersonalAccessToken;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(CustomPersonalAccessToken::class);
    }
}
```

I think it's clear the provider is ignoring the Sanctum method. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

The only error I get is expected because it's trying to reach the wrong schema and table:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'websites.personal_access_tokens' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql,
> SQL: select exists(select * from `personal_access_tokens` where

I need it to reach:

```
vendorinv.PersonalAccessToken
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like your code matches the docs. I would dive into the Sanctum code and look and see if that's the case, but I doubt they would release it with that broken. It should have test cases in place. Make sure you clear your cache and run `composer dumpautoload` to make sure there are no caching issues present.

Comment: I ran composer dumpautoload, still doesn't work. I looked in the Sanctum vendor folder, but I didn't see any tests. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Make sure the `AppServiceProvider::class` is located in `bootstrap/providers.php` file if you're using Laravel 11. I looked at the latest release of Sanctum and if you have that code in the provider and it's booting, you should be using your model. Have you tried using `dd('hit')` in your boot method to confirm it's being loaded? I would run `composer update` to make sure you're up to date. Is it possible to try to create a new project since it seems early and pull in sanctum from how it says in the docs and set the custom model that way? If it's not working, then that's an issue with Sanctum

Comment: Hi! I just did little demo with your setup and all works fine. Does issuing API tokens work ok?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did find the bug, it was on my end. On my login, I was checking to see if a token already existed, and I was using the DB facade to do that check, so of course it was checking the wrong place. Once I switched to eloquent and using the model, it worked perfectly.  Thanks again for the comments, it helped me drill down into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was on my end, I was using the DB facade to do a check on the token in my login method. So of course that was checking the wrong db. Once I switched to using the new model, everything worked. Thanks for the helpful comments, they pointed me in the right direction.